# Angular Material Tooltip not working after upgrade to Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular11

I have been using the Angular Material tooltip in my application, but when I recently upgraded to Angular 11, it has stopped working. I created a test component with the following code in the template, which I copied directly from https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview

```
<button mat-raised-button
        matTooltip="Info about the action"
        aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over">
  Action
</button>
```

I have Chrome dev tools open, and I can see changes to the template happening when I hover, but I still cannot see the tooltip on the screen.

I have Angular Material installed, and I have imported all necessary modules, so I am not sure what the issue is (possibly just a bug in Angular Material?)

Comment: Can you please share your code as this is working fine in angular 11.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5c1338?file=src/styles.scss

Comment: Something quick to check: If you say you can see the HTML change relevant to expecting the tooltip to show - is it being rendered behind other content? Have you got anything's z-index set higher than the tooltips?

Comment: Ok, so I think I see what is happening. The tooltip itself looks to be appearing with no background (I would expect a gray box around it), so it appears to be invisible. I made the background of my page blue and I can see the tooltip text in white letters. I suppose now I just need to figure out why the background styling is messed up. @Krenom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a custom theme .scss file. I found that I needed some entries for tooltip in the theme, which I did not have before. Not sure why this is needed now but wasn't before. I added

```
tooltip: map_get($mat-grey, 700)
```

to a couple spots in my scss file. See [github.com/angular/components/issues/18139](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18139)